# Postgresql update from CTE

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I have 2 simple CTEs from that return the same columns, but with diff values

```
with x as (select id, class from table1 where paramenter='D')`, 
    y as (select id, class from table1 where paramenter='F')
```

I want to update column 'class' in Y cte so that all id's from cte 'y' will have the same class as in cte x
I tried something like this, but it doesn't work

```
update table1 set class=x.class from x where x.id=y.id
```

Comment: You can't update a CTE, only a table

Comment: in this statement I try to update the table, using values from CTE, but looks like something is wrong here
```update table1 set class=x.class from x where x.id=y.id```

Comment: `with x as (...), y as (...) update x set x.class = y.class from y where y.id = x.id`. See https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html.

Comment: @OlegP That should work, with `from table1 x …`. Also you still need the `where` clauses for the `parameter` value

Comment: Is `id` the primary key of that table? If yes, how are the rows from `x` and `y` matched with each other? It would help if you could [edit] your question to provide the table definition for `table1` as well as some sample data and the desired result.

Comment: how about this:  
```with y as  (select id, class from table1 where Parameter='F')
 update table1 t  set class=y.class from y
 where id in (select id from table1 where Parameter='D') and ID=y.ID

Comment: @OlegP Please [edit] your question, where you can also easily use [formatting](/help/formatting), instead of responding in comments

Comment: how about this:  
```with y as  (select id, class from table1 where Parameter='F')
 update table1 t  set class=y.class from y
 where id in (select id from table1 where Parameter='D') and ID=y.ID```  
still not working, but at least there is some logic in it

Comment: @OlegP But yes, that should work. You can simplify by using just `where Parameter='D' and ID = y.ID` instead of `where id (select …) and ID = y.ID`. Assuming of course that you have multiple rows with the same `id` and different `parameter` values.

Comment: @bergi thank you for your comments. I've made some adjustments and looks like it worked.